# Set Value based on current value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an update statement

```
    Merge [dbo].[Profiles] AS P
using Staging.[AWSProfiles] AS S
 ON P.PIN = S.PIN
WHEN Matched THEN UPDATE SET 
 P.[FirstName] = S.[FirstName]
 ,P.[LastName] = S.[LastName]
 ,P.[SupervisorLastName] = S.[SupervisorLastName]
 ,P.[SupervisorFirstName] = S.[SupervisorFirstName]
 ,P.[SupervisorPin] = S.[SupervisorPin]
```

In my table `Profiles`, I have a field called `EmployeeStatusChangeDate`. I want to set this value to `GETDATE()` whenever the value from `EmployeeStatus` (field from `AWSProfiles` goes from 'Active' to 'Temp-out'

**AWSProfiles Columns**

```
FirstName
LastName
SupervisorLastName
SupervisorFirstName
SupervisorPin
EmployeeStatus
```

**Profiles Columns**

```
FirstName
LastName
SupervisorLastName
SupervisorFirstName
SupervisorPin
EmployeeStatusChangeDate
```

How can I do this in my update statement?

Comment: So you want this to automatically change? If so, you need a trigger on AWSProfiles

Comment: @KamilG. Is there a way to avoid the use of triggers?

Comment: Well, if you only want to change it every time you run an UPDATE then yes, but if not, then this UPDATE statement doesn't seem to be connected to what you want to do.

Comment: I agree with Kamil on this.  You'll either need to do this manually with a separate UPDATE each time or you'll need a trigger.  The 3rd option is to put `EmployeeStatusChangeDate` and `EmployeeStatus` on the same table.